# Migrating websites between servers for the first time

Tags: migration, website

For the past week I've been non-stop singing the [classic Foreigner tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Tl-kOcnn1U) at work because I've never migrated anything from one server to another before, and like a nervous teen on prom night, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing.

I have a total of three environments to migrate:

1. Development
2. Test
3. Production

My current plan is to migrate the most current version of the development environment that is approved for production use to the new development environment, then migrate the same version again to test and production (for clarification I'm a newly hired software developer; hooray for other duties as assigned).

I have no issues with performing the task aside from my lack of knowledge and I am looking forward to the task as a major learning experience. Each environment (to my knowledge at this point) has a SQL server (2008 R2) and a hosting server running Windows (2008 R2). We are upgrading from SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2016 SP2, and from Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 2012 R2.

I've been told that I do not have to worry about copying databases from the old SQL server to the new one since our infrastructure team will handle that transition. This task I could actually complete as I've done it many times before and all of the servers have already been set up and now just need their content migrated.

My issue is that since I have no idea what I'm doing in regards to migrating between servers, I'm not sure of everything I need to be thinking about for this migration. So far I have a list of all the obsolete databases that are no longer used or needed and can therefore be exempt from the migration.

Since my primary focus right now is on migrating the company website I believe I need to consider the following:

- All application pools.
- All applications running on the server.
- Any bindings that exist.
- Ensure that all settings on the new server match the old server.

However, I know that I am not thinking of everything and am needing help to come up with a list of things that need to be done and accounted for.

---

What are the many things that need to be done or accounted for when migrating a website from an old server to a new one? I know this will vary on a case by case basis, but a good foundational starting point would be great!

Comment: "Love" is zero points in Tennis! or was it some other tune?

Comment: @Jasen Not entirely sure I follow (could just be this really long day I'm having); I did update the post with the song of my intent, but would love to understand your pun there.

Comment: I searched "Foreigner" and found "I want to know what love is"

Comment: @Jasen hahahaha yeah that would fit too! Thanks for getting that stuck too!